# How to use HSPI?

Tags: hspi

May be stupid question. I created HSPIPluginB1 project from template, it compiles, runs and connects to HS.
But I've got no idea what to do next? How do I create devices, triggers, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. HSPIPluginB is described [here](http://hspi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#c). There's *some* help in the forum thread linked therein, but, for the most part, that HSPI template doesn't do much more to help. Your best bet, for now, is to hunt through the HS developer forum and documentation (https://homeseer.com/developer-support/). Honestly, it's pretty difficult to write a HomeSeer plugin as is, but that's not the fault of the HSPI project.

Fortunately, I'm working on HSPIPluginC. It's significantly easier to understand, but it's not finished. You can get a glimpse of where I'm going with it by checking out https://github.com/alexdresko/HSPI/issues/77#issuecomment-322885054. If anything, there's probably some useful code in there to help you move forward.

If you have any ideas for how HSPI can be made better, please [Create an issue](https://github.com/alexdresko/HSPI/issues) or start up a conversation in the [chat room](https://gitter.im/HSPI/Lobby)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did read ALL available info, not much help there.
Did you see a VB example plugin https://forums.homeseer.com/showthread.php?t=177339
It's got examples of most functionality, including triggers/conditions, config and status pages, etc. But it's VB which I don't like much.
But I guess I could use the VB code and convert it to C#

Comment: I just started with HS and don't have much understanding, so I'm afraid I can't contribute much at the moment. But I really want to be involved to make it better.
The reason why I start looking into plugin development - I kind of hate the way HS is designed, it looks pretty old school and I think with plugins we can make HS a bit more useful, especially for non-so-technical users.